# SpaceX Starship landing on Moon or Mars: why doesn't it fall over?

Tags: mars, the-moon, spacex-starship

How does the [SpaceX Starship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship) design accommodate uneven landing surfaces that might not be stable under the weight of the vessel?

I don't understand how SpaceX's Starship would be able to land on unprepared surfaces on the Moon or Mars. It is 50 meters tall, with 6 relatively small landing legs, so to me that sounds a lot like a tall building with no foundations. What are the odds of finding a perfectly flat level surface that won't yield under the enormous pressure on each of the legs?

Comment: Is there any reason why you think they won't be landing on a prepared landing area?

Comment: SpaceX's own concept art? https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geekwire.com/2019/nasa-checks-spacexs-potential-starship-landing-sites-mars-water-mind/amp/ Also the concept of the Starship is that it can function as a primary exploration vehicle.

Comment: Also, do you think the weight of Starship would mean it couldn't stand on its own on Earth, either? If no, what about Mars do you think makes the difference? If yes, why do you think SpaceX would bother building something that can't stand on its own here on Earth in order to be able to launch in the first place?

Comment: Starship is 50 meters (~150 feet) tall minus the booster. On Earth Starship currently stands on concrete - very different from the martian or lunar regolith. The issue is not whether the ship can support itself, which it clearly can, but how we can be reasonably certain the unknown regolith on the Moon or Mars can support it.

Comment: Also whether and how the Starship design can cope with imperfections like slight inclines or surface rocks.

Comment: This runs dangerously close to the internet meme "I see a problem I can't solve so hundreds of engineers at SpaceX must be wrong."   Perhaps you could reword it as "How does the Starship design accommodate uneven landing surfaces? "

Comment: I will clarify the question body along those lines. I don't mean to suggest the SpaceX engineers are wrong, I simply want to understand how the problem can be resolved.

Comment: They’ll contract Boston Dynamics. Problem solved.

Comment: and after even getting it right landing, will the regolith support so many tons of thrust on takeoff ?
I think thats why one the mars landing vehicles has a drill sampler in it.

Comment: Does it really matter? There is the question of supporting the weight of the fueled spacecraft, but once the engines are lit, and assuming rubble is not flung somewhere it can do harm, the effect on the ground no longer matters.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In my experience, I've noticed that SpaceX uses a lot of temporary components until such temporary components need to actually be tested. Since the legs of MK1, MK2, and most probably MK3 will never see uneven soils rather than concrete landing pads, they will most likely just have simple legs. After a few successes with MK3, we should start seeing much more articulate landing legs that will dynamically adjust to uneven terrain. But for now, it's just an additional engineering effort that is not yet ready for testing. SpaceX has demonstrated that it doesn't put the cart before the horse with many components (unless it's for a press conference, then they do get creative at times!)

Answer (score 12):

Quick answer is all I have time for now -- if someone wants to do a more detailed and referenced answer, please feel free and I'll delete this:

While it's very big, its mass is not that high, and gravity is low. On Mars, for instance, it needs about 150 tons of fuel, plus 100 or so tons of vehicle (mass) to get back to orbit. Under Mars gravity thats only just under 100 tons of weight on the legs -- a couple of fully loaded trucks. It's not surprising that a large truck can drive across a desert supported only by the contact patches of 16 tires.

Comment: Ok... Now make the trucks vertical, stack one on top of the other, crowd all the wheels around the base, and leave it standing there for a year waiting for an Earth-return launch window?

Comment: Which brings us to the question of what Mars soil is like mechanically. We should have at least some idea of that by now from the various landers and rovers. It's will be somewhat different from Earth -- no liquids, so no muddiness.

Comment: I have a hunch that when large, fully loaded trucks drive across a desert they do it on terrain *already known to be amenable to truck driving* whereas on Mars there is (disappointingly) not so many previously characterized deserts.

Comment: Yes there are plenty of places in deserts where trucks would get stuck. And the lesson from the Mars InSight mole is that there is a lot we don't know about Mars soil.

Comment: The landing may also serve to blow away (or even melt) some of the surface material.As someone once said of Project Orion -- "you don't have to worry about choosing your landing site, by the time you get to it it'll be flat!".

Comment: Lower surface gravity, perhaps unintuitively, means that an object at rest is less stable, easier to topple than in 1 g. That is why Apollo rovers and landers had such a wide base and low center of gravity. Even if it can stable itself at a Moon landing, tourists moving towards the windows at 50 m height could make it lean over, unless they iterate the design somehow.

Comment: @MilesMutka  oh those dang tourists! :-) -- sort of like that lady last week who climbed into a lion cage for a selfie.

Comment: @MilesMutka While that's true if the surface is rigid, less gravity will reduce the ground loading. If one leg is lower, bears more weight than the others, potentially causing it to sink more and move the CoM even further in that direction...

Comment: @SteveLinton, rockets do not blow terrain flat. They excavate holes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InSight#/media/File:PIA23301-MarsInSightLander-PitsMadeByThrusters-20181214.jpg. Note that those holes are excavated by only 140kg of landing thrust. This adds another hazard to landing on unprepared surfaces - flying debris blown back at the landing vehicle.

Comment: We're all a bit more familiar now with what happens when you fire a SpaceX rocket at the ground for launch or landing:  https://www.sciencefriday.com/segments/spacex-explosion-launch-debris/  Of course, the landing/launch rockets on Mars would not need to be as powerful, but then you'd also have even less prepared infrastructure there.

Answer (score 0):

Modern radar and similar sensors are more than good enough to identify flat landing spots (old lake beds, lava flows, wind-scoured plains, etc.) from orbit. I don't know if we currently have such sensors around Mars - we have some orbiters that are attempting to survey the planet, but perhaps not in such detail as could support finding a landing site - but Starship could presumably carry such as a payload, or several could be launched (perhaps by Falcon 9 or Falcon Heavy vehicles since Starships will presumably remain rare for a while) a few weeks or maybe months earlier than the Starship(s) launch.

Additionally, we have a small but useful amount of Martian surface data already, from landers and especially rovers. While they've probably not specifically been searching for landing sites for a 50m tall 200T (counting payload) vehicle, NASA and other space agencies have amassed considerable information on the immediate surrounds of their landers and rovers. Aiming for such spots might be a bit tricky on a planet with no GPS, but the landing program can permit small alterations in the destination based on terrain, using radar, LIDAR, or similar sensors for fine-grained detail. Starship certainly has the ability for terminal maneuvers before landing; SN8 translated significantly during its flight, rather than just going up and down.

Unmanned Starships could also pilot the way - this is part of the plan - and unload a robot that could set about preparing a landing site. Even if a few of those Starships fail to land safely, all it takes is one with the ability to determine a safe spot for landing, and then ensure that one or more additional safe spots exist in the vicinity.

All of the above is even more true for Luna than for Mars.